# Stuck in "Import Developer Profile" screen While Trying to submit my App

Tags: macos, xcode5, code-signing, mac-app-store, bundle-identifier

I am struck in this page

[image]
I am using XCode 5.

1. I create Bundle ID in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/‎
2. I create the Mac App Id in https://developer.apple.com/ using the Bundle ID
3. I used the Bundle Id in my App Target in xcode
4. I used the Mac App Id (Step 2) in the Provisioning Profile in XCode 5
5. Code Sign of XCode says - Mac Developer - this is where i think there is something wrong

All i do is xcode > archive > validate and i get the above screen

Any anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other answer said, You are right now trying to use your developer  provisioning profile to compile the app to the appStore.

To create a Distribution profile & certificate:

Login to developer.apple.com, Under iOS Developer Program click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
Click on "Certificates" and create one with the type "iOS Distribution" , once done under "Provisioning Profiles" click on Distribution, and create a provisioning profile targeting your App Id.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Mac Developer signing identity is for development signing.

To submit to the store you need two Mac Developer certificates:

- 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Company
- 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Your Company

Have you set them up in iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 0):

After a clean install of xcode 5.1.1 this issue got resolved automatically